# Does Athena have ref cursors?

Tags: query, cursors, aws-athena

Does Athena have a Ref Cursor type construct ?  Our team members have written pyspark sql in the following format

```
SELECT dr.case__c as caseId,
    collect_list(struct(
        dr.id as documentId,
        dr.name as documentName)) as documentRefs
FROM athena_db.docref dr
group by dr.case__c
```

I am not familiar with pyspark yet, hence trying to translate the above to an sql statement to run on Athena on AWS Console.  I am trying to write an Athena sql query to translate the pyspark sql.  I saw CURSOR is a reserved word in Athena, but haven't found any examples of how to use it.

If it is possible to convert above to regular SQL that I can execute on Athena, can someone please give me code  or point me to any examples?

Thank you